# $scope assignment works in one case but in other

Tags: angularjs, angular-controller

**First Case**

```
angular.module('tss.application').controller("UserspaceController",  function($scope, $http)
{
        $http(
            {
                url     : "/dirlist",
                method  : "GET",
            }).then(function successCallback(response) 
            {
                $scope.lists = response;
            }, 
            function errorCallback(response) 
            {
                window.alert("Dir list could not be get");
            });

});
```

**Second Case**

```
angular.module('tss.application').controller("UserspaceController", function ($scope, $http) 
    {
        $http.get('dirlist').success(function(data) 
        {
            $scope.lists = data;
        }); 
    });
```

I am very new to Angularjs so this could be a stupid questions. Anyway,
the assignment of lists variable works in second case but in first. That is, the second can access the values of "lists" inside the controllers. I failed to understand what is wrong with the first case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
angular.module('tss.application').controller("UserspaceController",  function($scope, $http)
{
        $http(
            {
                url     : "/dirlist",
                method  : "GET",
            }).then(function successCallback(response) 
            {
                $scope.lists = response.data;
            }, 
            function errorCallback(response) 
            {
                window.alert("Dir list could not be get");
            });

});
```

The deprecated `success()` method passes two separate values for data and headers, but the promise interface using `.then()` passes only a single `response` value which has the data and headers as attributes.

The change to your code is simply the line:

```
                $scope.lists = response.data;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
angular.module('tss.application').controller("UserspaceController",  function($scope, $http)
{
        $http(
            {
                url     : "/dirlist",
                method  : "GET",
            }).then(function successCallback(response) 
            {
                $scope.lists = response.data;
            }, 
            function errorCallback(response) 
            {
                window.alert("Dir list could not be get");
            });

});
```

put  $scope.lists = response.data;, will work